CircuitTooWideForTarget error when using Clifford simulator in Qiskit
I want to use the local Clifford AerSimulator with the Estimator primitive in Qiskit to calculate expectation values on Clifford circuits, but I am getting a CircuitTooWideForTarget error:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as Estimator_Aer

simulator_aer = AerSimulator(method="stabilizer")
estimator_aer = Estimator_Aer()

print(simulator_aer.num_qubits)
print(simulator_aer.coupling_map)

qc = QuantumCircuit(50)
job = estimator_aer.run(qc, 'I'*50, backend=simulator_aer)
print(job.status())
print(job.result())

outputs
10000
None
JobStatus.ERROR
[...]
CircuitTooWideForTarget: 'Number of qubits (50) in circuit-165 is greater than maximum (30) in the coupling_map'

This is strange to me, since the backend object simulator_aer doesn't have an associated coupling_map object, and should support thousands of qubits. Something under the hood is implicitly limiting the number to 30.
Does anyone know how I might go about resolving this?

I can get it to work by instead defining the estimator via estimator_aer = Estimator_Aer(backend_options=dict(method="stabilizer")) and doing away with the simulator_aer object altogether. Nonetheless, I'd be interested in finding out why this method doesn't work.
